# Encoding Problem char looks right but is not

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

First it is not the common utf8 Problem. All parts of my application is set to utf8 and works fine.

I get a mail over IMAP by PHP and fetch the title. In this title I have s special char. A ö from the German language. Now I search in my DB if there is an entry with this title. I know there is one. Database use utf8mb4_general_ci for encoding to be able to store 4 bit utf8 encoded special chars.

Title from Mail:

Fw: Auflösungsvertrag

Entry in Database:

Fw: Auflösungsvertrag

I put the cursor behind the ö and tried to delete it. First the ö switched to an o and after the second press of the delete key it was fully gone. If I type now and ö over my keyboard, MySQL finds the entry.

If I put both inside notepad ++ You see

Fw: Auflösungsvertrag

FW: Auflösungsvertrag

If you turn the encoding to ASCII you get

Fw: AufloÌˆsungsvertrag

Fw: AuflÃ¶sungsvertrag

So you can see now that the two ö are different encoded, but they get displayed right. So my mySQL select don't find the DB entry.

Can someone explain this to me and give me a hint for a php command to turn the first encoded string to the second one?

I bit longer description how this problem accrues:

I write a ticketing system. Every mail I send out get added the tickets ID to the subject. If I send out a mail I write it to the db in an outgoing table. Then a cronjob sends this mails out asyncron. I use PHP mailer and send over SMTP.

I fetch Incoming mails by IMAP and the PHP IMAP classes. If a mail comes in with an TID in the subject I merge this mail into the ticket in the database. All ticket entries are grouped by the TID column.

The problem is now, if you send a mail from the system to another mail address inside the same system, you get the mail merged into the existing ticket.

That's why I look in the outgoing table for every incoming mail by search for the from Address, to Address and the title. If I find the mail I know the system has sent it out.

So if I send the mail out I have the first encoding. If I get the same mail back in again it has the other encoding. Both encoding seam to be valid utf8 encoding. Everywhere on the website I get the right character and also in the db I get it displayed right. Only if I make an SQL query over PDO, MySQL treat them as two different characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

The topic is called Unicode equivalence and there are methods that normalize.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence

PHP also have a class for this.
https://www.php.net/manual/de/normalizer.normalize.php

I had to call

normalizer_normalize( $myString, Normalizer::NFKC );

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would solve this and according to me it has to be fixed once for all with a oneshot instruction on the database side, and not with just a trick on the PHP, that you would have to repeat everywhere each time you are facing the issue.

First I copied your 2 strings :

```
Auflösungsvertrag
Auflösungsvertrag
```

Into Notepad++, in which I do have the (very handy) HEX pluggin.

When I turn the text into HEX, I have those values

```
4175666c6fcc8873756e677376657274726167
4175666cc3b673756e677376657274726167
```

If we split that, we see easily the HEX of the 2 ö that causes issues

```
4175666c 6fcc88 73756e677376657274726167
4175666c c3b6   73756e677376657274726167
```

The trick is now to tell MySQL to replace all characters having those HEX values from one to another, ie `6fcc88` to `c3b6`

And you can do that with this statement that uses [UNHEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex) function

```
UPDATE your_table
SET your_column=REPLACE(your_column, UNHEX('6fcc88'), UNHEX('c3b6'))
```

### Example and reproduction below

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
/* Creating test data  - Row 1 and 2 are identical */
create table test (id int, txt varchar(50), txthex varchar(100));
INSERT INTO test (id,txt,txthex) VALUES (1, 'Auflösungsvertrag', '4175666c6fcc8873756e677376657274726167');
INSERT INTO test (id,txt,txthex) VALUES (2, 'Auflösungsvertrag', '4175666c6fcc8873756e677376657274726167');
INSERT INTO test (id,txt,txthex) VALUES (3, 'Auflösungsvertrag','4175666cc3b673756e677376657274726167');
```

---

**Applying fix**

```
/* Running oneshot fix on row 2 only */                                                      
UPDATE test 
SET txt=REPLACE(txt, UNHEX('6fcc88'), UNHEX('c3b6'))
WHERE id=2
```

---

**Check Query**

```
SELECT  id, txt, txthex hex_original, 
        CAST(UNHEX(txthex) AS CHAR(30)) unexed_original , 
        HEX(txt) hex_replaced
FROM test;
```

| id | txt | hex_original | unexed_original | hex_replaced |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Auflösungsvertrag | 4175666c6fcc8873756e677376657274726167 | Auflösungsvertrag | 4175666C6FCC8873756E677376657274726167 |
| 2 | Auflösungsvertrag | 4175666c6fcc8873756e677376657274726167 | Auflösungsvertrag | 4175666CC3B673756E677376657274726167 |
| 3 | Auflösungsvertrag | 4175666cc3b673756e677376657274726167 | Auflösungsvertrag | 4175666CC3B673756E677376657274726167 |

---

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

The problem is that new added entries to the DB will again not work and it is not only one special char there are also Ö ä, Ä ü, Ü, ? and that are only the German once.

I think it has something to do with utf8 utf16 utf32 encoding. But in my tests I could not find a command that could convert a to b. I added some more explanation to the first post.